# Calculating double sum

Tags: summation

How do I calculate this sum (as a function of n)?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm9mC.png]

I have no experience in calculating sums like these, so I don't know any of the rules regarding this subject.

Comment: the first term contains $\log(0)$

Comment: Brute force it.  Calculate the inner sum for $i=0$, then calculate it for $i=1$, then do it again for $i=2$, and continue this until $i=n$.  Then add all of these results together.

Comment: Let's say that log(0) is 0 in this case. Even start from j=1, i=1. What will be the reslt in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the brute force, you could write
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i i j \log(ij)=\sum_{i=1}^n i \log(i) \sum_{j=1}^i j+\sum_{i=1}^n i\sum_{j=1}^i j\log(j)$$ Thie most inner sums can be computed
$$\sum_{j=1}^i j=\frac{1}{2} i (i+1)$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^i j\log(j)=\log (H(i))$$ where appears [the hyperfactorial function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html).

So, by the end
$$S_n=\frac 12\sum_{i=1}^n \left(2 i \log (H(i))+i^3 \log (i)+i^2 \log (i) \right)$$ I do not think that we could simplify further.

Answer (score -2):

This really seems like an expression that would be better calculated by a computer than by hand. It can be done in Python with two **for loops**.

```
import math
sum = 0
for i in range (0, n+1):
    for j in range (0, i+1):
        sum = sum + (i * j) * math.log(i * j)
```

Comment: While it is useful to know a computer can be used to give a numerical answer, this doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking for.